# How to know all Bazel targets affected by a git commit?

Tags: git, bazel

A git commit may change some [workspace rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html), some source files, .bazelrc, etc. How to get all Bazel targets affected, thus need to rebuild and test, after such change?

In Buck, we can run `buck targets --show-rulekey //...` to see all rule key changes between two Git revisions. Is there any equivalent command in Bazel?

Answer (score 7):

See [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/scripts/ci/ci.sh):

```
# Under Apache 2.0 licence
COMMIT_RANGE=${COMMIT_RANGE:-$(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)".."}

# Go to the root of the repo
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"

# Get a list of the current files in package form by querying Bazel.
files=()
for file in $(git diff --name-only ${COMMIT_RANGE} ); do
  files+=($(bazel query $file))
  echo $(bazel query $file)
done

# Query for the associated buildables
buildables=$(bazel query \
    --keep_going \
    --noshow_progress \
    "kind(.*_binary, rdeps(//..., set(${files[*]})))")
# Run the tests if there were results
if [[ ! -z $buildables ]]; then
  echo "Building binaries"
  bazel build $buildables
fi

tests=$(bazel query \
    --keep_going \
    --noshow_progress \
    "kind(test, rdeps(//..., set(${files[*]}))) except attr('tags', 'manual', //...)")
# Run the tests if there were results
if [[ ! -z $tests ]]; then
  echo "Running tests"
  bazel test $tests
fi
```

Take also a look at [bazel-diff](https://github.com/Tinder/bazel-diff).

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an answer, but this bazel-discuss thread may be helpful: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/I9udqWIcEdI/iczVgWLOBQAJ "Selecting bazel targets to run in CI - possible approaches"